# Bokeh application development workflow

Tags: python, bokeh

I'd like to develop a Bokeh application and based on the [documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#building-bokeh-applications), it seems best to run the `bokeh serve --show app.py` locally when developing the application.

After running the command, the application launches in a new browser tab and works correctly. However, it's not clear to me how to edit the code and rerun the application because once the tab is closed, the application continues to run in the terminal and the only way to exit is through `kill <pid>` which is somewhat inconvenient.

What is a good workflow for developing a Bokeh application?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a mac, you can stop the application with `ctrl+c` from terminal. This will shut down the app. Then you edit the code, save it and rerun `bokeh serve --show app.py` from terminal. That's all.

Note that the application should continue running as long as your browser window is open. If you change the inputs using the widgets in your dashboard it will print out logging in terminal, as it updates the dashboard according to your code.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the tab will only close the *client* session. To kill the *server* process, indeed you need to kill the process somehow. Ctrl+c is convenient from the terminal. If you are in an IDE like PyCharm, I suggest setting up your configuration to run bokeh like a python script via `python -m bokeh serve --show`. Then you can use your IDE's start/stop/restart functionality also.

FYI if you are in Pycharm 2017.x, your script name should be the script or directory (for directory-based apps) of the bokeh app and interpreter options should be `-m bokeh serve --show`

I typically also set up another configuration for debugging which runs the script like a typical python script (no special interpreter args). This will allow you to use your IDE's debugger for any issues basically up to the initial page load. For any debugging beyond that (i.e. callbacks), I typically use a combination of logging and/or manual `pdb.set_trace()` calls.